# rspec test with email format validation failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm following the RoR tutorials; I stuck at email format validation part. I checked three times with the code from the book, there was nothing missing or wrong, but I got this error:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb

...[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
....F

Failures:

  1) User when name is not present when email format is valid should be valid
     Failure/Error: expect(@user).to be_valid
       expected #<User id: nil, name: " ", email: "user@foo.COM", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to be valid, but got errors: Name can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:37:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:35:in `each'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:35:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.07755 seconds
8 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:33 # User when name is not present when email format is valid should be valid
```

spec/models/user_spec.rb file:

```
    require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
 before { @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com") }
  subject { @user }
  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }

  it { should be_valid }
  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }

 describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                     foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        expect(@user).not_to be_valid
end 
end
end
  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        expect(@user).to be_valid
      end
    end
  end
end
end
```

app/models/user.rb file:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
end
```

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place which has lead to you nesting everything inside the "when name is not present" block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A name needs to be set in order for it to be valid.

Look at the specification you wrote:

```
describe "when name is not present" do
  before { @user.name = " " }
  it { should_not be_valid }
end
```

So if you want your email test to pass, you need to ensure a name is set beforehand.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering this question, but "before { @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com") }" Does this part already ensure the name is "Example User" ?

Comment: See Frederick Cheung's comment. You nested it all in the name is not present block. I unkowningly corrected it in my answer.

Comment: Thank u, i figured it out, it's problem of "end"